# How to arrange the sln, projects and folders to help the team keep GRASP principals

Tags: c#, visual-studio, oop

Usually we create project for each application layer: BLL, UiLogic,Dal

and in them folders - but there are no guidelines.

I believe it has to be different.

I wish there were some good practices and guidelines for **how to arrange the sln, projects and folders** to help the team keep these principals:

[GRASP on wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GRASP_%28object-oriented_design%29)

I want to collect all the Pocos and interfaces in one separate project ("contracts")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question is betters suited for programmers.stackoverflow.

That being said I don't think that having too many projects is ok for people to understand the code, especially if the separation is arbitrary. In your case you have multiple kinds of separations, first by application layer, than by use in the code. I used to do that too until I realized that is was just cargo cult programming and there was no logical way to explain the splits.

Having guidelines helps. Having the guidelines fit on a single page helps even more.